# Propel with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, propel, cakephp-3.0

I'm interesting in using cakePHP with Propel as ORM. I've find this simple  [guide](http://blog.anas-mughal.com/?p=48) but it's old and many features are different.
As well as I've created with Propel models and configurations files but now I can't understand where put this file.
Anybody has experience with this interaction?

Comment: Please always mention the CakePHP version that you are using and tag your question accordingly.

Comment: @ndm Sure, I've just  edited it

Comment: I would start by reading the propel docs and then putitng their bootstrap logic inside the `config/bootstrap.php` file of your app. Out of curiosity, why would you use propel instead of the CakePHP ORM?